# div scrollbar not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use css infrequently, but I thought that the following should create a scrollable area.  Instead, it seems to just hide all the text that doesn't fit but provides no way to scroll.  Behavior seems the same in chrome/ie/firefox, so I'm guessing I'm just doing something wrong.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="history" class="scroll-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac euismod nulla. Fusce enim tortor, elementum ut volutpat non, interdum ut nunc. Vestibulum placerat mi vel risus ultricies non bibendum urna vestibulum. Curabitur volutpat, turpis vel suscipit accumsan, lectus nibh blandit sem, ut elementum massa tortor quis augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis cursus lacus ac diam sollicitudin tempor. Vivamus at sagittis lacus. Donec augue neque, cursus in tristique at, mattis vitae eros.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#history {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 8px;
}

.scroll-area {
    overflow-style: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Non-scrolling picture example]

Comment: did you try .scroll-area {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  The overflow: hidden was definitely the problem!  Appreciate all the super fast responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're using [`overflow-style`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/overflow-style) which isn't supported in any major browser yet ..

Setting `overflow` to auto or scroll on `.scroll-area` will have the vertical scrollbar appear as expected

http://jsfiddle.net/kRcaR/1/

Comment: Selected this answer for the tip about lack of browser support.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly set `overflow` to `auto` (or to `scroll` if you need scrollbars appear all the time):

```
.scroll-area {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/aNTHx/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `overflow: auto` or if you just want the y-axis to scroll `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden`;

Answer (score 1):

Your div should have this overflow styling for vertical scrolling:

```
.scroll-area {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Or if you want to scroll horizontal:

```
.scroll-area {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hiding the scroll bar with `overflow: hidden;`.

If you change to:

```
.scroll-area {
    overflow-style: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="history" class="scroll-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac euismod nulla. Fusce enim tortor, elementum ut volutpat non, interdum ut nunc. Vestibulum place
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#history {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 8px;
}

.scroll-area {
    overflow-style: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/YxsLc/1/
```

**EXPLANATION**

If You want to scroll content in html elements You should use property `overflow: scroll`;

Goodluck in future code.